# How come I can "read" from a file which is opened in "write mode" in C Language?

Tags: c, linux, windows, fopen

I've been testing file operation function in C Language. However, I found out that I can **read** a file which is opened up in "**write mode**" and that is not what I expected.

Firstly, I test the code on **Windows and compiler by g++** and find out the this strange result then I move to **Linux** and test the same code compiled by g++ and the result is what I want!

Could anyone tell me what's going on on Windows when I use the fopen(), fread(), fwrite().

**Here is my test code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
**strong text**
int main(int argc, char*argv[]){
    
    FILE *fp = fopen("123.txt","w");
    char buf[50];
    strcpy(buf,"hello world");
    int n_read = 0;
    int n_write = 0;

    if(fp){
        printf("file exist!\n");
        n_write = fwrite(buf, 1, strlen(buf), fp);
        printf("write n: %d\n", n_write);
        // fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
        // fflush(fp);
        n_read = fread(buf, 1, 5,fp);
        printf("read n : %d\n",n_read);
        printf("buf now : %s\n",buf);       
    }
    else{
        printf("error !\n");
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Result on Windows**

```
file exist! 
write n: 11 
read n : 5 
buf now :
```

**Result on Linux**

```
file exist!
write n: 11
read n : 0
buf now : hello world
```

I noticed that if I put `fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);` or  `fflush(fp);` on Windows test, the result is the same as Linux one and that is what I expected but I still don't know why.

Comment: On Linux, you could use [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) to understand the [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) done by your executable. And [GNU libc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) is free software: you are allowed to download its source code and study it. On Windows, I recommend using your debugger. Your code could have [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Read [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)

Comment: Confirm for MSVC Windows 7. Another oddity I have previously noticed is that if I use `fread` to read into a buffer that is larger than the file (in a single call), the upper part of the buffer beyond the file length can get written to as well. Obviously, I passed the actual buffer length, which was larger than the file. IOW if the buffer was originally zeroed, then after `fread` the supposedly unused part of the buffer can contain non-0 values.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch , very appreciate it! let me check the [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) out .

Comment: @WeatherVane, well, that's weird too ! Have you checked the return value of fread()? Maybe you could check the content and the size by HEX-Editor plug-in inside the notepad++.

Comment: Yes, that is how I know where the end of the 'read' part of the buffer is.

Comment: @WeatherVane, I've tested what you said on Windows 10 and it works without that problem.

Comment: Windows 7 doesn't do that on a small file: it is for a large file, the one I just tried was 94 Mb with a single call to `fread` and a buffer size 100 Mb. Obviously, the buffer can't be local. The rogue data is duplicated part(s?) from the actual file content.